# how to match with protobuf oneof syntax in typescript for serialization and deserialization

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

i have proto message as following:

```
message values{
 oneof val{
 int32 int_val=1;
 string string_val=2;
 }
}
```

```
so how construct interface in typescript for same so that i can deserialize in C# ?
```

Comment: What library are you using for serialisation in TypeScript? The interface doesn't really matter, only the proto message definition.

Comment: JSON.stringfy() is what i used.. please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: No, protobuf is not JSON.

Comment: Thanks @bergi. i have found one answer like :** interface values{ val:Val} interface Val{ IntVal:number, StringVal:string}** this helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best match for `oneof` is an algebraic data type.

`protobuf-ts` is a typescript code generator plugin that implements this. (I'm the author).

For example, the following proto:

```proto
message OneofExample {
 // Only one of (or none of) the fields can be set
 oneof result { 
   int32 value = 1;
   string error = 2;
 }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
interface OneofExample {
 result: { oneofKind: "value"; value: number; } 
       | { oneofKind: "error"; error: string; } 
       | { oneofKind: undefined; };
}

let message: OneofExample;
if (message.oneofKind === "value") {
 message.value // the union has been narrowed down
}
```